# ordered collection with duplicated value (key ,value)

Tags: java, collections

i want to know if there is a collection with those properties :

1. Key ,Value
2. allow duplicate value
3. ability to order it by value  and conserve at the same time duplicate value.

for example :
  no ordered

```
(1,2)
(2,1)
(3,1)
(4,2)
```

ordered

```
(2,1)
(3,1)
(1,2)
(4,2)
```

i tried `treeMap`  using comparator but it's remove duplicated value

```
@Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Comparable valueA = (Comparable) map.get(o1);
        Comparable valueB = (Comparable) map.get(o2);

        int res = 0;
        if (valueA.compareTo(valueB) < 0) {
            res = 1;
        } else if (valueA.compareTo(valueB) > 0) {
            res = -1;
        } else {
            res = 0;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code, the way you used `TreeMap`?

Comment: @RohitJain `TreeMap` does not allow duplicate values

Comment: How are entries with the same value to be ordered? In your example, would the ordering `[(3,1), (2,1), (1,2), (4,2)]` be acceptable?

Comment: I wonder if a `collection` is a "tool, library or favorite off-site resource"?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg It doesn't allow duplicate keys. Values, sure it does.

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Java, but I don't think that there is such a collection (at least not one which will order the keys of the same value). Have you tried writing your own class of key-value pairs with its own sorter, then getting the whole thing into simple sorted collection?

Comment: @RohitJain Correct. I meant keys of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Guava's [`TreeMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) to create an ordered multimap. This orders the values *within  the same key*, but if you need to have iteration ordered by values, then the best you can do is swap the key and value (and forego the ability to look up by key).

Comment: As far as I know, a `TreeMultiMap` only provides for ordering on keys, not values.

Comment: @TedHopp First sentence of the javadoc: "Implementation of Multimap whose keys **and values** are ordered by their natural ordering or by supplied comparators." (emphasis added)

Comment: @yshavit - That refers to the order of the collection returned by `get` and other methods related to a single key. Please show us what API call will return an iterator for the entire collection ordered by values (which is what OP is asking for).

Comment: @TedHopp You're not going to find a collection where overall iteration is ordered by values but still allow lookup by key. If the latter can be done away with, then just swap the key and value.

Comment: @TedHopp Ah, I misunderstood the OP's requirements, thanks. I thought they wanted it sorted by key, then value. You're right.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - Then that should have been your answer. Saying "use `TreeMultimap`" when it doesn't (directly) do the job that OP needs, and without an explanation of how a solution could be built on top of `TreeMultimap`, is not really much of an answer.

Comment: @TedHopp Edited the post to be clearer about the limitations of my approach.

Comment: To complete what I believe are the OP's requirements (which seem to suggest looking up by key), you'd need two objects: a `Map` going key -> val and a `TreeMultimap` going val -> [keys]. For full encapsulation, it'd be good to put those both as private fields of a new class that supports the high-level operation (put, get-by-key, iteration of key-value pairs sorted by value, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Just read again what do you want to get it!

You want ordered values.

```
(2,1)
(3,1)
(1,2)
(4,2)
```

When, in what cases do you want? I believe you need to switch the key and value and take an ordered key collection.

with duplicates I would use a collection. Something like this:

1 - > (2,3)

2 - > (1,4)

Something like:

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer,  ArrayList<Integer>>
```